# Replace every name in a file by its google translation

Tags: javascript

I have a stations.js file that look like that :

```
module.exports = [
  {
    name: 'センター',
    assetID: '01101010',
    latitude: 43.062222,
    longitude: 141.354167,
    mongoID: 'b822dff1e50760b99248',
  },
  {
    name: '北１条',
    assetID: '01101520',
    latitude: 43.062222,
    longitude: 141.353889,
    mongoID: '493062f76e253bd5cbe6',
  },
...
]
```

I want to replace all the japanase names by their english translation from Google API (I haven't work on that yet for now let's say I want to replace them by a random work like "hello").
For example I want to rewrite my file like so :

```
module.exports = [
  {
    name: 'hello',
    assetID: '01101010',
    latitude: 43.062222,
    longitude: 141.354167,
    mongoID: 'b822dff1e50760b99248',
  },
  {
    name: 'hello',
    assetID: '01101520',
    latitude: 43.062222,
    longitude: 141.353889,
    mongoID: '493062f76e253bd5cbe6',
  },
...
]
```

That's the first time I do something like that and I'm pretty lost. For now my code looks like that :

```
const fs = require('fs');

function runScript() {
  fs.readFile(process.argv[2], 'utf8', function (err,data) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    fs.readFile(process.argv[3], 'utf8', function (err,logs) {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
      }
        const newSta = {}
      const rawNewSta = logs.match(/\s*name:\s*'(.*?)'/g)
      rawNewSta.map(id => ({
        name: id.split(`'`)[1],
      })).forEach(station => newSta[station.name] = "hello")
      console.log(newSta)
      const splitFile = data.split(Object.keys(newSta))
      let body = splitFile.reduce((acc, val) => `${acc}${val}name: '${readName(val, newSta)}',`, '')
      body += splitFile.splice(-1)
      // console.log("->", body)

      fs.writeFile('stationsNew.js', body, function (err) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        console.log('stationNew.js created');
      });
    }) 
  })
}

function readName(stationStr, newSta) {
  const station = stationStr.match(/name:\s*['"](.*)['"],/g)
  const name = station.splice(-1)[0].split(/name:\s*['"]/)[1].split(/['"],/)[0]
  return newSta[name] ? newSta[name] : ''
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array of objects, so you can just work with it as an array of objects instead of doing all this string manipulation you're trying.

```js
// in real life use `import` here
module = {}
module.exports = [
  {
    name: 'センター',
    assetID: '01101010',
    latitude: 43.062222,
    longitude: 141.354167,
    mongoID: 'b822dff1e50760b99248',
  },
  {
    name: '北１条',
    assetID: '01101520',
    latitude: 43.062222,
    longitude: 141.353889,
    mongoID: '493062f76e253bd5cbe6',
  }
]

for (item of module.exports) {
  item.name = "hello" // or go get the translation here and substitute it in
}

console.log(module.exports) // in real life use fs.writeFile()
```